# How can I prevent the default onRowClick action from being executed when clicking on an item in a table row?

Tags: java, internet-explorer, richfaces, seam, ajax4jsf

In a legacy application based on Seam 2.2, jsf 1.2, and Richfaces 3.3, I am having a problem with Internet Explorer:

I have a datatable with clickable rows. Clicking on a row will open the detailed view of the item.
The last column contains a trashbin icon. When clicking the icon a confirmation dialog appears. When not confirmed, nothing else should happen. This works fine on Google Chrome.

It doesn't work with Internet Explorer (testing on Version 11). Here, the default action `action="#{myAction.select(k)}"` is executed.
I tried adding `event.preventDefault();` to the `event.stopPropagation();` but that did not help.

How can I get this to work on Internet Explorer?

```
<rich:dataTable id="myDatatable" value="#{list.model}" var="k"
                headerClass="tableheader"
                onRowMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='#F1F1F1'"
                onRowMouseOut="this.style.backgroundColor='#{a4jSkin.tableBackgroundColor}'"
                rowClasses="clickableRow">
    <a4j:support event="onRowClick" id="onRowClickEvent"
                 action="#{myAction.select(k)}"
                 reRender="myDatatable"/>

    <rich:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <a4j:commandLink action="#{list.changeOrder('k.name')}" 
                    value="Name #{list.orderColumn == 'k.name' ? (list.orderAscending ? '▲' : '▼') : ''}"
                    reRender="myDatatable" ajaxSingle="true" limitToList="true"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{k.name}"/>
    </rich:column>

    <rich:column style="text-align: center;">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <a4j:outputPanel layout="block">
                <h:outputText value="Delete"/>
            </a4j:outputPanel>
        </f:facet>

        <a4j:outputPanel onclick="event.preventDefault();event.stopPropagation();">
            <s:graphicImage value="/img/bin_closed.gif" style="cursor: pointer;">
                <a4j:support event="onclick"
                             action="#{myAction.delete(k)}"
                             ajaxSingle="true" limitToList="true"
                             onsubmit="if(!confirm('Are you sure?')) { return false; }" />
            </s:graphicImage>
        </a4j:outputPanel>
    </rich:column>

</rich:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by replacing `event.preventDefault();event.stopPropagation();` with `Event.stop(event);` as described in the answer to this question:
[Stop JSF Event Chain, Answer by prageeth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13808405/stop-jsf-event-chain)